# Email detection in EditText not working Android

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I want a way to login into my parse account with either my username OR email. But the code I'm working on cease to work. 
Highly appreciated if you can point out whats wrong. 
You can find some of the code below,

```
    private class SignInOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Get the username and password from the view
        final String username_email = mUsernameEmailEtxt.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
        final String password = mPasswordEtxt.getText().toString();
        if (isFormInputValid(username_email, password)) {
            if (emailValidator(mUsernameEmailEtxt.getText().toString())) {
                final String email = mUsernameEmailEtxt.getText().toString();
                ParseUser.logInInBackground(email, password, new LogInCallback() {
                            public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                                if (user != null) {
                                    // Hooray! The user is logged in.
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class)
                                            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY |
                                                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                } else {
                                    ParseUser.logInInBackground(username_email, password, new LogInCallback() {
                                        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                                            if (user != null) {
                                                // Hooray! The user is logged in.
                                                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class)
                                                        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY |
                                                                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                                startActivity(intent);
                                                finish();
                                            } else {
                                                findViewById(R.id.error).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });

                                }
                            }
                        }
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

UPDATE: Ive changed my code according to @grundyboy34. I can login with my username, but not with my email.

```
public static boolean emailValidator(final String email) {

    Pattern pattern;
    Matcher matcher;

    final String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@" + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

    pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
    matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
    return matcher.matches();

}

private class SignInOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Get the username and password from the view
        final String username_email = mUsernameEmailEtxt.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
        final String password = mPasswordEtxt.getText().toString();
        if (isFormInputValid(username_email, password)) {
            if (emailValidator(mUsernameEmailEtxt.getText().toString())) {
                 final String email = mUsernameEmailEtxt.getText().toString();
                ParseUser.logInInBackground(email, password, new LogInCallback() {
                            public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                                if (user != null) {
                                    // Hooray! The user is logged in.
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class)
                                            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY |
                                                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                );
            } else {
                ParseUser.logInInBackground(username_email, password, new LogInCallback() {
                    public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                        if (user != null) {
                            // Hooray! The user is logged in.
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class)
                                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY |
                                            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            findViewById(R.id.error).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }}}
```

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: @njzk2 well, the code compiles without error but fails to login With username OR email.

Comment: does it produce any errors?

Comment: @e4c5 no. but login doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like your logic statements aren't nested into the proper scopes.
Try this:

```
private class SignInOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // Get the username and password from the view
    final String username_email = mUsernameEmailEtxt.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
    final String password = mPasswordEtxt.getText().toString();
    if (isFormInputValid(username_email, password)) {
        if (emailValidator(mUsernameEmailEtxt.getText().toString())) {
            final String email = mUsernameEmailEtxt.getText().toString();
            ParseUser.logInInBackground(email, password, new LogInCallback() {
                        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                            if (user != null) {
                                // Hooray! The user is logged in.
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class)
                                        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY |
                                                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            } 
                        }
                    }
            );
        } else {
            ParseUser.logInInBackground(username_email, password, new LogInCallback() {
                public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                    if (user != null) {
                        // Hooray! The user is logged in.
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class)
                                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY |
                                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        findViewById(R.id.error).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can login with my Username, but not with my email tho. Is this some issue regarding parse?

Comment: is emailValidator() returning true when you enter an email?

Comment: Yes, but fails to login Using Email.

Comment: You should debug your logInInBackground method then.